# openTSDB is checking for zookeeper at port 2181. How can I change it to make it point to another port

Tags: opentsdb

openTSDB is checking for zookeeper at port 2181. How can I change it to make it point to another port. Am not able to find any configuration file where we can make change so that openTSDB will check for another port.

Answer (score 0):

at what port is your zookeeper is running?
If you are running opentsdb following this step:

```
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html
```

when you are running opentsdb you can specify your port no

> ./build/tsdb tsd --port=4242 --staticroot=build/staticroot --cachedir="$tsdtmp" --zkquorum=myhost:2181

myhost:2181 is zookeeper hostname and port no. Change the port no.